# How to access a private docker registry by script without exposing the credentials?

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to include a build script in order to pull and build a private image. I would docker login with my username and personal access token and then pull the image.

That way I am exposing these credentials in the repository, which is not very secure. How would I manage such an authentication?

This is my script with exposed credentials:

```
deploy:
    ssh <user>@<ip> "docker login registry.example.com -u <user> -p <token> && docker-compose up"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use GitLab's project-level or group-level [**secret variables**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables).

> Project-level variables can be added by going to your project's **Settings > CI/CD**, then finding the section called **Variables**.
>
> [image: variables screenshot]
> <sub>(source: [gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/img/secret_variables.png))</sub>

Variables you enter here will be available in all pipelines that run.

```
docker login -u $MY_USERNAME -p $MY_PASSWORD
```

If you're using GitLab as your private docker registry, you don't even need a special user - you can login with `$CI_JOB_TOKEN`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't knew about that. Perfect! I will use these because I want to gain access to a different registry, so $CI_JOB_TOKEN won't work, I think. That's a great solution, thank you a lot.